# How can I get an emulator/AVD for a specific update like Android 2.1 update1?

Tags: android

I need to reproduce a bug that I think is on devices running Android 2.1-update1.  The emulator options exist for 2.1 but I don't see option for update 1?  It is important to be able to test for all device scenarios, so i need to know how to create AVD for a specific update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the emulator to match exactly devices, you can only test against "vanilla" Android releases from Google.

Unless you can get images from the device manufacturer or source code for the kernel (which you should be able to find or request) and of the Android framework (which will be quite more challenging to obtain) that you can recompile and generate the proper images, then you are out of luck.

INHO, the emulator is really a great tool to help you develop applications, but it does not replace a real device when it comes to testing.

Comment: Ok. but how am I for example going to find a device running Android 2.1 -update 1.  I am trying reproduce a bug that I think is for that version of the SDK.

Comment: I know what release it is, but I am having trouble creating the AVD to match.

Comment: Which part do you have trouble with?

Comment: Let me give you a concrete example.  I'm getting crash reports on listView.removeFooterView(View)

Comment: removeFooterView is implemented differently in Android 2.1 update1

Comment: after update 1 its going to check if the adapter is null before trying to remove. I want to run my code thru a 2.1 update 1 emulator to see whats going on.  I don't have time to go find 2.1 update 1 device.